# Magento2 + Fishpig Wordpress Integration - Wordpress RSS Feed Not Working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am using Magento2 + Fishpig Wordpress Integration. WordPress Rss feed not working  in my project. Please help me how to solve this issue.